# Outlook 2010 exchange setup prompts for username@domain.local rather than email@domain.com

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, email, outlook

We use a hosted exchange service.

When users want to set up Outlook 2010 to access their account, they open Outlook and run through the configuration steps.

Autodiscover is enabled, and in the user's active directory profile, their email address is in the email field.

However, when the configuration process reaches a point where they are prompted for their email account's username and password, their active directory username is filled in by default instead of their email address. Is there a way to fix that?

[image: Outlook Username Prompt]

Users get confused and try to enter their email password over and over again and wonder why it doesn't work (and completely miss/ignore the "use another account" button even though they have instructions right in front of them).

I'm also using the Office 2010 ADM's in group policy, but I haven't yet seen an option to specify what gets auto-populated in that windows security prompt.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the user's `UPN (User Principal Name)` in Active Directory to the same value as your user's e-mail addresses. The UPN seems to get displayed in this dialog box.

Comment: 1) how would you do that? 2) Would it mess up existing users?

Comment: You would do that in Active Directory, in AD Users & Computers, on the user, under the "Account" tab. If you need a new Suffix (@domain.com), there is a guide [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772007.aspx).

I don't know if it messes up existing users in your environment. This depends if you use the UPN anywhere yet. Best to test it out with a few test users probably

Comment: An alternate UPN is not in place. I'd assume that a new user profile would be generated when the domain for the alternate UPN is selected, which wouldn't be. I also wouldn't want the email domain's DNS responses to be coming from the domain server (rather than an outside DNS server). I'm thinking that this solution won't be ideal in this environment.