# Add generic credential using group policy?

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, credentials

In Windows 7, if I go to `control panel > user accounts > user account > manage your credentials`, there are credentials saved for the local user.

Is there a way to add a generic credential using group policy on server 2008?

Comment: Why would you want to do something like that?

Comment: To possibly address this issue: http://serverfault.com/questions/409756/outlook-2010-exchange-setup-prompts-for-usernamedomain-local-rather-than-email

Comment: Just to clarify, you're looking to set the password of a bunch of domain users to a generic value?

Comment: The primary goal is either to set the username to the active directory user's email address, or just set the username to blank. The network address should be set to `MS.Outlook:email@domain.com` and the username to `email@domain.com`. I don't care about the password, as I won't actually be providing it through the credential.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think there is a way to do this.
But what you want could maybe be accomplished by setting the User's `UPN (User Principal Name)` to the same value as your e-mail address.

Comment: 1) how would you do that? 2) Would it mess up existing users?

Comment: You would do that in Active Directory, in AD Users & Computers, on the user, under the "Account" tab. If you need a new Suffix (@domain.com), there is a guide [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772007.aspx).

I don't know if it messes up existing users in your environment. This depends if you use the UPN anywhere yet. Best to test it out with a few test users probably